# AWS Security Group Not Permitting Inbound Traffic

Tags: security, networking, amazon-web-services

I want to allows nodes in the `app-server` group talk to mysql and redis machines in the `database` group.  However,  I can only make explicit IPs work for ingress rules.  When I try to define groups instead, to make auto-scaling easier, the traffic is blocked.

*Here's my setup*:

When I run

`ec2-describe-group database`

I get

```
PERMISSION      890752071609    database        ALLOWS  tcp     3306    3306    FROM    USER    890752071609    NAME default    ID sg-5ce3766c  ingress
PERMISSION      890752071609    database        ALLOWS  tcp     3306    3306    FROM    USER    890752071609    NAME app-server ID sg-b81b8088  ingress
PERMISSION      890752071609    database        ALLOWS  tcp     6379    6379    FROM    USER    890752071609    NAME default    ID sg-5ce3766c  ingress
PERMISSION      890752071609    database        ALLOWS  tcp     6379    6379    FROM    USER    890752071609    NAME app-server ID sg-b81b8088  ingress
PERMISSION      890752071609    database        ALLOWS  tcp     0       65535   FROM    USER    890752071609    NAME database   ID sg-d262f1e2  ingress
PERMISSION      890752071609    database        ALLOWS  tcp     22      22      FROM    CIDR    0.0.0.0/0       ingress
```

However, when I try to connect to port 6379 using redis-cli from a machine in the `app-server` group, I get a redis timeout error.

If I explicitly add the elastic IP of the server I want to connect from, like this

```
PERMISSION      890752071609    database        ALLOWS  tcp     3306    3306    FROM    CIDR    111.snip.25/32        ingress
PERMISSION      890752071609    database        ALLOWS  tcp     6379    6379    FROM    CIDR    222.snip.25/32        ingress
```

the redis-cli call works.  However, I want to be more flexible, and add the entire security group instead.

The [amazon docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-examples) state

> By specifying a security group as the source, you allow incoming traffic from all instances that belong to the source security group. The incoming traffic that you allow is based on the private IP addresses of the instances in the source security group. You might specify another security group in your account if you're creating a three-tier web service (see Creating a Three-Tier Web Service).

This should work, no?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Few recommendations to check/ try:

1. AWS sec groups do *not* allow cross regions rules. I don't know if your Redis machines are in the same region.
2. Try to create this setup from AWS Web Interface or from Dome9 Console (www.dome9.com) to make sure that there are no hidden settings that are not displayed.

Don't loose hope - this kind of setup *should* work - AWS sec groups were designed for this use case.

Comment: Thanks Froyke, turned out to be the Region issue for me.